# In JavaScript if "Function" descends from "Object", then how was keyword function made available while defining the constructor of object?

Tags: javascript

I was recently reading some tutorials of JavaScript, and every article states that Functions descend from Objects.
The above statements leads to an understanding that Objects were created before Functions were available. 
If it is so, then how can constructor of an Object be a function (As per my understanding object Function hasn't been created yet)?

Please help me out with this confusion.

[Functions Descend from Objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMq8I.png)

Comment: This is not an evolutionary timeline à la chicken-and-egg… one doesn't "beget" the other. `Object` is a global object which simply exists. It is the prototype of `Function`. That's it. Period. Don't overthink it.

Comment: Note that the `Object` constructor doesn't really "exist" as a function, rather [its behaviour is defined](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2).

Comment: @deceze: I am trying to understand the thought behind this implementation because otherwise the documentation could have said they just exist. However, it specifically states that Functions are descendants. Thanks for answering though, but I am keen to know how is this circular reference (if it is one in the first place) managed.

Comment: @JamesThorpe: The documentation shared you shared actually describes the use Objects as functions, and then as constructors (basically functions again). 

`var foo = Object(2)` // > Does a type casting and produces an object Number. 
`var foo = Object()` // > Creates a copy of the object itself.
`
Question I was trying to put is how is something available before it is declared, or probably which is declared at the same level if not before.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript functions are basically objects.

They are what is called **first class objects** - meaning they can do anything that an object can and are basically interchangeable.

Therefore all properties and methods available on the object level are also available on the function level.

You might want to read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen)

Answer (score 0):

> How can constructor of an Object be a function

The short answer is that you are trying to understand something that is irrelevant to understand in order for you to use the Javascript language for coding.

---

The longer answer is that you must distinguish between built-in objects:

- [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)
- [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype)
- [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype)

and the objects you create yourself as part of your code.

The **built-in objects** are part of the Javascript language and are simply available to you out-of-the-box. Your question relates to the internal workings of the language as you are inquiring about how the built-in `Object` is constructed. This has little value to understand unless you are looking to become part of the team developing the Javascript language.

The **objects you create yourself** as part of your code is almost always linked to other objects via the objects *internal* `[[Prototype]]` property. So if you for example do:

```
var x = {"foo": "bar"};
```

you have now created your own object with the property `foo` and the value `bar`. You can then do:

```
console.log(x.hasOwnProperty("foo")); //true
```

even though `x` does not have a method called `.hasOwnProperty()` directly on it. The reason the above code works is, that `x` is linked to the built-in `Object.prototype` via `x`'s internal `[[Prototype]]` property and via this link  delegates to `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`. So all the objects you create  as part of your code has access to use the methods on `Object.prototype`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am just curious to know. Let me search for native code, and understand it. Much appreciated!